# SSH key already exists on bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, laravel-forge

I was trying to add the SSH key of my server in laravel-forge to bitbucket. The ssh key is usually located in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` inside the laravel-forge terminal. Bitbucket did not allow me to add this. This is usually added in bitbucket by clicking 'Access Keys' under 'Settings'. The error message was: `that key has already been added by a user`. But I could not find which other user in the team had added it. The bitbucket site could not show me which user had added it.

Answer (score 3):

I want to answer my own question so that it helps someone. After I contacted bitbucket, I came to know that a specific user had used that ssh key. All I did was create a new ssh key using `ssh-keygen` command in the laravel-forge server terminal. I was successfully able to add this new ssh key for laravel-forge in bitbucket and I was able to deploy.

Comment: I think one of the things that also affects this is if you rename the machine after it's provisioned.

Comment: hi sir. laravel-forge server terminal means u ssh forge@yoursite.com inside you execute that ssh-keygen then it will automatically reflect on forge dashboard as new token?